# Extraction of filenames with dirent

Tags: c++

Could You tell me, how to put only filenames (without directories) into my vector within following code?:

```
int getDir (string dir, vector<string> &files)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL) {
        cout << "Error (" << errno << ") with " << dir << endl;
        return errno;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        cout << dirp << endl;
        files.push_back(string(dirp->d_name));
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does a socket, symlink, block device, character device or FIFO get counted with the files or the directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
struct stat eStat;
stat(dirp->d_name, &eStat);
if(S_ISDIR(eStat.st_mode))
    printf("found directory %s\n", dirp->d_name);
```

Better to use S_ISREG in place of S_ISDIR

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat), and check the `st_mode` field with the `S_ISDIR` macro.

Comment: Or `lstat()` if you need to identify symbolic links separately from the object that they link to.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS. Under Linux, the dirent structure returned by `readdir` looks like this:

```
      struct dirent {
           ino_t          d_ino;       /* inode number */
           off_t          d_off;       /* offset to the next dirent */
           unsigned short d_reclen;    /* length of this record */
           unsigned char  d_type;      /* type of file; not supported
                                          by all file system types */
           char           d_name[256]; /* filename */
       };
```

so you can examine the d_type field to see if you have a directory or a file.